# Clarify how installing Bazel on windows works?

Tags: windows, installation, bazel

So I'm following the install instructions for Bazel 2.0, and basically it seems like all I have to do is download the ".exe" file, add it to the path, and then I can use it from windows powershell (probably bash too, although I haven't tried). What I want to know is - does the ".exe" file do any manipulation of my system (outside of the obvious compiling work) or download anything else under the hood? I ask because I want to try it out while working on a restricted computer system, as I'm sure some of you have encountered before.

Answer (score 2):

It will extract itself into the location where it also (unless configured otherwise) keeps its build output. By default this would be under current user's home directory. The location can be changed with [`--output_user_root`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--output_user_root) parameter or [`TEST_TMPDIR`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html#current-layout) environmental variable. You can check out the [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html) for more detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Ondrej K.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60441335/7778502):

- Yes, you just download the .exe and add it to your PATH. Do not run it from Bash though, because [it's broken](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html#running-bazel-msys2-shell-vs-command-prompt-vs-powershell). (I'm linking to the documentation at `master` as of 2020-02-28 and as of `2.1.0` being the most recent version. The current `master` will become the release doc for `2.2.0`.)
- Yes, Bazel will download stuff. This includes tools for the languages you build (e.g. Java), and also external dependencies of the project.
- Yes, Bazel will write to disk even if you just run it once: as Ondrej K. wrote, it will extract itself to a directory.
- Do not set `TEST_TMPDIR` to tell Bazel where to run. Setting this envvar will make Bazel believe it's running inside a test, and it will significantly reduce its resource use and change its behavior in subtle ways you probably don't want. (If you want to limit its resource use, you can do so with several flags, see [`--jobs`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.1.0/user-manual.html#flag--jobs) and [`--local_ram_resources`, `--local_cpu_resources`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.1.0/user-manual.html#flag--local_%7Bram,cpu%7D_resources).)